# Having trouble targeting key presses to complete an action

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have Prev/Next buttons. With the code I'm about to provide, it adds and removes a class `.fadeaway`.

```
$("a.next").click(function(){
        var elem=document.querySelector("#project-container");

        elem.classList.add("fadeaway");
        setTimeout(function(){
        goToNextProject();  
        elem.classList.remove("fadeaway")
        }, 350)

        return false;
    });

    $("a.prev").click(function(){
        var elem=document.querySelector("#project-container");

        elem.classList.add("fadeaway");
        setTimeout(function(){
        goToPrevProject();  
        elem.classList.remove("fadeaway")
        }, 350)

        return false;
    });
```

On a side note, I bet there's a way to combine these two. So the problem lies with the keypress. I currently have js to also navigate the prev/next items with arrow keys.

```
function activateKeyNav()
    {
        // Description: register keypress event on document object
        jQuery(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
            switch(event.which)
            {
                case 39: // right
                    goToNextProject();
                    break;

                case 37: // left
                    goToPrevProject();
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm not sure how to create the animation that `.fadeaway` does, it's `0` so it fades in and out the `#project-container`. I need it where if the left or right keys are being pressed it's adding and removing the `.fadeaway` class like the `a.next` and `a.prev` is doing.

To get a working example, click on the prev/next buttons [here](http://darrenbachan.com/#/stories).

Comment: can you create fiddle?

Comment: @DarrenBachan Combining the two event handlers is okay. What is the other thing that you are asking ? A fiddle would be helpful

Comment: @Chintan I'm not sure how to build a fiddle for this. The #project-container I targeted loads data from a string. The prev/next buttons opens and closes the #project-container. It's complicated, it's not ideal, but it's the way it's currently built. The best example I can show you is the link in my post, when you open a project and click prev/next buttons you'll see the div fades. I need the arrow keys to do the same thing.

Comment: @DarrenBachan You want to add the `fadeaway` class on arrow key press ?

Comment: @Chintan no, take a look at my post and see what a.next/a.prev are doing. I need that to happen when the arrow keys are pressed. Imagine I replaced "a.next" with "arrowkey-right".

Answer (score 2):

You can write a wrapper function which adds fadeaway class and does setTimeout.

```
function toggleFadeAwayClass(){
    var elem=document.querySelector("#project-container");
    elem.classList.add("fadeaway");
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        elem.classList.remove("fadeaway")
    }, 350)
}

function activateKeyNav()
    {
        // Description: register keypress event on document object
        jQuery(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
            switch(event.which)
            {
                case 39: // right
                    toggleFadeAwayClass();
                    goToNextProject();
                    break;

                case 37: // left
                    toggleFadeAwayClass();
                    goToPrevProject();
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: This is really close. I updated the files so the link in my original post shows this code. It's weird. The prev/next buttons fade nicely, but with the arrow keys I see the div, it fades out, and fades back in.

Comment: After experimenting more with this, I had to remove it. It ended up making any key on the keyboard trigger .fadeaway.

Comment: Oops, I missed it. You need to add the call inside the switch case. Updated the response

Comment: This solved it so that the arrow keys only work, but for some reason the fade isn't working correctly. The .fadeaway class has opacity:0. Removing it makes it 1. Basically while the next project is appearing it fades it out then in, but for some reason with the arrow keys it appears, fades out, then fades in. I don't know why its doing opacity 1, 0, 1. The prev/next buttons fade exactly how I want it to.

Comment: Looking at how the prev/next buttons work. It adds .fadeaway to #project-container, goes to the next project, then removes that class. Now, in the code you provided, it goes to the next project and then adds .fadeaway.

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the js to know exactly how the fading works, and using partial code from another answer, this is how I made it fade exactly how I wanted it to:

```
function activateKeyNav()
    {
        // Description: register keypress event on document object
        jQuery(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
            switch(event.which)
            {
                case 39: // right
                var elem=document.querySelector("#project-container");
                    elem.classList.add("fadeaway");
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        goToNextProject();  
                        elem.classList.remove("fadeaway")
                    }, 350)
                    // toggleFadeAwayClass();
                    // goToNextProject();
                    break;

                case 37: // left
                var elem=document.querySelector("#project-container");
                    elem.classList.add("fadeaway");
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        goToPrevProject();  
                        elem.classList.remove("fadeaway")
                    }, 350)
                    // toggleFadeAwayClass();
                    // goToPrevProject();
                    break;

                case 27: // escape
                    hasher.setHash();
                    projectClose();
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
```

I thought that if `var elem=document.querySelector("#project-container");` was defined I didn't need it anymore, so I tried it without it and `elem` was not defined so it created a console error. Is it possible to establish this variable at the very top so I don't need to keep writing it?